# Textbox (with scrollbar) in MS Word inaccessible after a copy is made

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

A while ago, I filled out an MS Word textbox (with scrollbar) in some application form on a Windows PC. My computer then crashed but I was able to get back that Word file today and opened it using MS Word in my Macbook.

Here's the situation. First, the doc file was in read-only mode, so I created its copy. However, in the copied version, all the textbox is not accessible (as shown in the picture below): the scrollbar of the textbox does not work and I could not move the cursor inside the textbox to make any edit. I was trying to read the content of the textbox but to no avail. The textbox now appears as an image rather than an editable textbox with a working scrollbar. Is there anyone who had the same problem? How did you access the content of the textbox in MS Word?
What seems to be the problem? Does this have anything to do with the Word version mismatch (say because the file was created in MS Word for Windows and now it is opened in MS Word for Mac)? Any clue how to recover this is appreciated. Please help!

[image]

Comment: You need to post the document online, if you want us to examine it.

Comment: Could you please open the doc file back on Windows machine? It seems that Word for Mac does not support the textbox with scrollbar.